# Everything you believed isn't true

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for the feeling you get when everything you've believed (in any particular topic) is no longer true to that belief? It feels like your stomach fell to your feet and you suddenly lose your trust in what you once believe. It isn't disappointed or devastated (but it is that severity of emotion).

Comment: Why not disappointment ?

Comment: Disillusioned perhaps?

Comment: There is a term for this, but it's not coming to me at the moment.  *Disillusionment* is the best I can come up with right now, but there's something better.

Comment: Please write a sentence and leave a black at the place of the intended word.

Comment: And why not *devastated*?

Answer (score 0):

You should include a sample sentence to give us some context.

That said, I'm not sure that I've learned a single word that specifically describes an up-is-down reversal of belief, but you could use anything that carries a connotation of betrayal or abandonment (e.g. betrayed, forlorn).

You could also try something along the lines of confusion (e.g. flummoxed, bewildered, discombobulated).

Or perhaps "invalidated" is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word **epiphany.** [Etymologically](https://www.etymonline.com/word/epiphany#etymonline_v_8789), it meant: an appearance or manifestation especially of a divine being.

The contemporary meaning of the word epiphany also includes a neutral connotation. It does not restrict only to positive realization, but also means negative or neutral realization of something.

> a usually sudden manifestation or perception of the essential nature or meaning of something.